# Getting Cannot use import statement outside the module when try to run yarn test

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am new to Jest and I'm trying to run yarn test for my React Native application. When I run it, I am getting the following error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**{"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { isIphoneX } from "react-native-iphone-x-helper";**
^^^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
> 2 | import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
    | ^
  3 | const screen = Dimensions.get('screen');
  4 |
```

Pacakage.json

```
 "jest": {
"preset": "react-native",
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
  "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
],
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|react-native-responsive-fontsize|react-navigation|@react-native-community|@react-navigation|react-native-animatable)"
]
```

}